# scala: change the port of a url

Tags: scala, url

I have the following url:

```
ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com/room/chat?username=felipe
```

And I'd like to just add a non-default port, like this

```
ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com:8000/room/chat?username=felipe
```

I first tried with java.net.URL to start parsing and manipulating the url, but I got

```
scala> val u = new java.net.URL("ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com/room/chat?username=felipe")
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ws
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:592)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
```

I didn't want to mess with regular expression, to avoid missing some strange case (but it's ok if there's no other choice, of course...)

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `java.net.URI` to extract to parts of the uri and then build the new uri string with the port added. Example:

```
val uri = URI.create("ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com/room/chat?username=felipe")

val newUriString = "%s://%s:%d%s?%s".format(uri.getScheme, uri.getHost, 8000, uri.getPath, uri.getQuery)

newUriString: String = ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com:8000/room/chat?username=felipe
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, this is the small utility helper that I came out with using the java.net.URI as drexin told

```
package utils.http

case class Uri(
  protocol: String, userInfo: String, 
  host: String, port: Int, 
  path: String, query: String, fragment: String
) {
  lazy val javaURI = {
    new java.net.URI(
      protocol, userInfo, 
      host, port, 
      path, query, fragment
    )
  }

  override def toString = {
    javaURI.toString
  }
}

object Uri {
  def apply(uri: String): Uri = {
    val parsedUri = new java.net.URI(uri)
    Uri(
      parsedUri.getScheme, parsedUri.getUserInfo,
      parsedUri.getHost, parsedUri.getPort,
      parsedUri.getPath, parsedUri.getQuery, parsedUri.getFragment
    )
  }
}
```

and I use it like this (from play's console):

```
scala> import utils.http.Uri
import utils.http.Uri

scala> Uri("ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com/room/chat?username=felipe").copy(port=8000).toString
res0: java.lang.String = ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com:8000/room/chat?username=felipe
```

Comment: I really like how you leverage the parameter default mechanism of the case class to create a new URI with only one parameter changed. And the same mechanism works for any change of 1..n number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `java.net.URI` instead.

```
def changePort(uri: java.net.URI, port: Int) = new java.net.URI(uri.getScheme, uri.getUserInfo, uri.getHost, port, uri.getPath, uri.getQuery, uri.getFragment)
```

and then

```
scala> changePort(new java.net.URI("ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com/room/chat?username=felipe"), 8000).toString
res: java.lang.String = ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com:80/room/chat?username=felipe
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but you can do this with `scala-uri` (disclaimer: this is my own library):

```
import com.github.theon.uri.Uri._

val uri = "ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com/room/chat?username=felipe"
val newUri = uri.copy(port = Some(8000))

newUri.toString //This is: ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com:8000/room/chat?username=felipe
```

It'a available in Maven Central. Details are here: https://github.com/theon/scala-uri

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try out my [Bee Client API](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client), which contains a [PartialURL](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/docs/bee-client/latest/#uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.url.PartialURL) class for processing URLs (complete or otherwise) according to their structure.

The general idea is to construct one from a string or URL and then alter any parts you need to, e.g.

```
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.url._
val url = PartialURL("ws://chat-jugar.rhcloud.com/room/chat?username=felipe")
val url8080 = url.copy(endpoint = Some(url.endpoint.get.copy(port = Some(8080))))
```